# Javascript class extension : calling base class-function from child-class function : seem to be calling static method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

This is complicated to explain but I've been on this for days now. I'm "extending" one Javascript "class" to another but calling a base-class method from a child-class method does not work properly. It seems as if the base-class-method "acts" as a static method : properties that are defined in the childclass somehow have their default values when calling a base-class-method from a-child-class method.

To keeps things simple I didn't include my elaborate code but created a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
function extend(Child, Parent){
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.base = Parent.prototype;
}

function BaseClass(){
}

BaseClass.prototype.randomNumber = 0;
BaseClass.prototype.functionA = function(){
     this.randomNumber = 200;
     this.functionB();
}

BaseClass.prototype.functionB = function(){
     alert(this.randomNumber);
     console.info(this);
}

function ChildClass(){

    this.functionB = function(){
         ChildClass.base.functionB();
    };
}

extend(ChildClass, BaseClass); 
var childInstance = new ChildClass();
childInstance.functionA();
```

I'm using firebug to log to the console. It output's "Baseclass" and this.randomNumber is somehow 0 while it is set to 200 in functionA.

the extend-method I'm using is simular to the one from Yahoo.lang.extend which I also tried with the same result.

I can't figure out if I'm missing something or this is just one of the drawbacks from "extending" Javascript and I'm actually calling a "static" method here.  Help would be much appreciated here.  Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do here because I find it complicated to put it in words. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

What happens in this line of code:

```
ChildClass.base.functionB();
```

...is that `functionB` is called with `this` pointing to `ChildClass.base`. This is because `this`, in JavaScript, is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where it's defined (unlike many other languages that have that keyword). To make that call whilst preserving the meaning of `this`, you'd use `call`:

```
ChildClass.base.functionB.call(this);
```

...which explicitly sets `this` during the call to be whatever you pass in (`this`, in this case). More: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) | [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

By the way, if you're interested in inheritance hierarchies and making calls into the parent object (I won't say "class," JavaScript doesn't have classes), I wrote this up a few years ago: [*Simple, Efficient Supercalls in JavaScript*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) It uses "class"-like terminology, which it really shouldn't (it's just helper methods to make hooking up hierarchies of prototypical inheritance easier), and it predates ECMAScript 5 (the latest version of JavaScript) which offers some features that would apply. So I need to update it, but it may be useful to you.

Comment: Very nice!  This was not explained in the book I read about Javascript inheritance. So in fact I was kind of calling a "static" method. I checked out your link ("Mystical methods"). Using     ChildClass.base.functionB.call(this); did the trick.  Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. Class is indeed not a good keyword, that's why I used quotes. I'm still having problems with "this" while using .call(this).  I'm working on Javascript image-carousels but "this" is all messed up.  I'm giving up here, terrible language it is.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick: It's not terrible, it's just different from what you're used to. Once you understand it, it's hugely powerful and flexible. I'm not saying it's a perfect language (there isn't one), and I'm not saying there aren't things I would improve, but it's actually very, very good once you understand it.

Comment: I've been programming in Javascript for 5 years so I'm quite familiar with it.  But compared to C# or Java this language is terrible.  Besides, the inheritance thing doesn't seem to work properly and has kept me busy for days now. I'm working for a company and have to get this finished. I'm using the .call(this) and still "this" is messed up.  I'm sorry I sound a little bitter here but this is frustrating.  Thanks for your responses anyway.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick: With respect, regardless of how long you've been using the language, if you still don't know how to manage `this`, you've never actually actually *learned* it. (You're not alone there.) If you're using `foo.call(this)`, then within that call to `foo`, `this` ***will*** be what `this` was when you did `foo.call(this)`. Full stop. If you're seeing something different, post a question and someone can explain what you're doing wrong (most likely, `this` isn't what you thought it was when you did the `call`).

Comment: Very true :).  But I'm not sure what to post cause I don't know where it's going wrong.  However I'm getting the slight impression JQuery is messing up my "this".  Here is code from my base class:

this.positionNavButtons(availableHeightForImage);console.info(me.config);  
var me = this;
 $(me.navLeftButton).show().click(function(){console.info(me.config);me.onNavButtonClickedHandler(true); });
Somehow var me has changed when the callback function is evoked by a click

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick: jQuery does set `this` for various operations; in particular in an event handler, `this` will be the raw DOM element on which the event was triggered. I don't see any problem with that code that would explain why `me` would be different later, are you assigning to `me` in code after you hook up the event handler? If you can post an example to http://jsbin.com, I'd be happy to help you figure it out. (BTW, meant to say earlier, completely agree that C# and Java are great languages *too*.)

Comment: I set var me = this prior to defining and calling JQuery methods cause "this" refers to JQuery inside JQuery. I checked out jsbin.com but I don't understand how it works : I don't seem to be able to insert HTML for some reason, only Javascript. Also, I can't save it - I'm assuming in order to share it with you I should be able to save it and send you and url. Guess I'll have to post another question on Stack Overlflow in order for me to find out how jsbin works, haha.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick: You can't figure out how http://jsbin.com works? When you go there, you should have a toolbar at the top, a JavaScript window on the left, and an HTML window on the right. (If either of those is missing, tick the relevant checkbox in the toolbar.) Add your stuff, click Render to see the result. Click Save to save the results so others can see them. (BTW, `this` inside a jQuery-attached event handlers **doesn't** refer to jQuery, it refers to the raw DOM element on which the event was fired.)

Comment: Thanks for your time, the save-option did nothing.  at this moment I'm on a different project that has to be finished first so I don't have time for it now,  thanks a lot anyway.  Maybe I'll get back to you on that later if you're ok with that.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick: That's so weird, I wonder what's up with it. No worries. We probably shouldn't continue "chatting" here in comments (in fact, we should probably clean up the ones above), but when you come back to it if you're still running into trouble, feel free to shoot me an email. It's on my profile. Best,

Comment: Thanks for the offer. concerning the abundance of comments : according to stackoverflow I'm not allowed to chat yet so I had to resort to comment-chatting :)